# Prove that $e_n = 5 \cdot 3^n + 7 \cdot 2^n$ for all integers $n>0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction

Suppose that $e_0; e_1; ...$ is a sequence defined as follows:

$e_0 = 12; e_1 = 29$

$e_k = 5e_{k−1} - 6e_{k−2}$ for all integers, $k > 2$.

Prove that $e_n = 5  \cdot 3^n + 7 \cdot 2^n$ for all integers $n > 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use induction:

1. Verify that the claim is true for $n=1,2$.
2. Suppose, it is true for $n$ and $n-1$, then for $n+1$ we have
   $$e_{n+1}=5e_n-6e_{n-1}$$
3. Use the induction hypothesis, and continue as follows
   $$=5\cdot5\cdot 3^n+5\cdot7\cdot2^n-6\cdot5\cdot3^{n-1}-6\cdot7\cdot2^{n-1}=$$
4. Continue, group them, pull out $3^{n-1}$ and $2^{n-1}$ and conclude.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so - once you've shown the equation holds for $n=1$ assume it holds for some $n=k$. So we can write

$e_k = 5 \cdot 3^k + 7 \cdot 2^k$

Now, look at $e_{k+1}$

We know recursively that $e_{k+1} = 5e_k - 6e_{k-1}$

Since you've assumed it's true for $e_k$ you can also assume it's true for $e_{k-1}$ (this is called strong induction). So

$e_{k+1} = 5 \cdot ( 5 \cdot 3^k + 7 \cdot 2^k ) - 6 \cdot (5 \cdot 3^{k-1} + 7 \cdot 2^{k-1})$

Providing I haven't made any mistakes, this term should cancel down to give you $e_{k+1} = 5 \cdot 3^{k+1} + 7 \cdot 2^{k+1}$

Which completes the proof by induction.

Answer (score 0):

This follows by the below *uniqueness theorem* for solutions of recurrences (difference equations). To apply it, check that the closed form satisfies the recurrence, with the same initial conditions.

**Theorem** $\ $ If $\rm\ f'_n,\ f_n\ $ are solutions of $\rm\ f_{n+1} = a_n f_n + b_n f_{n-1}\:$ then

$$\rm f'_0 = f_0,\,\ f'_1 = f_1\ \ \Rightarrow\ \ f'_n = f_n\   for\  all\,\ n\ge 0$$

**Proof** $\rm\ \ (Hint)\ \ $ Here's the inductive step. If $\rm\:f'_k = f_k$ for all $\rm\:k \le n\:$ then

$$\rm \begin{eqnarray} f_{n+1} &=\,&\rm a_n\, f_n + b_n\, f_{n-1} \\
&=\,&\rm a_n\, g_n + b_n g_{n-1}\quad by\ induction \\
&=\,&\rm g_{n+1}\end{eqnarray}$$